# Make description of “community-specific reason” close reason more clear

Tags: bug, feature-request, close-reasons

I wanted to close
*[Usage of DownloadToByteArray in Windows.Azure.Storage Version 3.0.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171854/usage-of-downloadtobytearray-in-windows-azure-storage-version-3-0-2-0)* as “too localised” because the author “found that she was using the wrong container name”.

But I was confused which option to choose as the close reason:

After some Meta search, I found the sub-reason “Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.” is hidden under the reason:

> **A community-specific reason (too old to migrate).** 
> This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline.

It is not intuitive. Can the reason header have some more generic wording and **remove “too old to migrate”** as it is misleading?

The details line of the reason should list possible sub-reasons including “Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.”

[In 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons/184567#184567) such option was named as “Off-Topic”.
A year ago the label text became site specific - see *[Goodbye “off-topic”, hello “community-specific reasons”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396592)* and *[Question Close Updates: Phase 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396754)*.

But clarification “(too old to migrate)” was not shown at that time and is not relevant for not-migration specific reasons.

There is a suggestion on MSE, *[Please reinstate the words “off-topic” into the closing dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346436/)*. 
I will be happy with any words that will make clear on the first page which sub-options are available, when the user chooses one.

Answer (score 36):

I wholeheartedly agree with this. The last re-organization and renaming of the close reasons was a *huge* mistake. I cannot tell you how many users I've seen confused by this, and I can honestly never even remember myself what the name of the category is when I'm telling users without close-vote privileges how to raise these "recommend closure" flags. (Spoiler alert: it's "needs improvement".)

Changing the name on the category would help, for sure. But the *real* problem is that **there are just too many close reasons, they're too deeply nested** (making for a confusing UI, where it's impossible to see all of the choices displayed in front of you at once), **and the descriptions of each individual reason are relatively poor**, leading to a lot of misguided closures.

I've been noodling about this for a while. I think, if it were up to me, I'd revamp the close reasons (yes, again; sorry), whittling them down to only 6 options—7, if you count duplicates:

1. **Too broad**

   > As currently posed, this question is too broad for our Q&A format. It either asks too many different questions at once, or a complete answer to this question would be prohibitively long (*i.e.*, would fill an entire book).
   >
   > Consider rephrasing this question to focus on only one problem, narrowing its scope so that it can be adequately answered within our Q&A format.
2. **Seeking opinions or recommendations**

   > The way this question is currently posed makes it likely to attract spam and/or answers that are primarily opinion-based. We cannot accept polls, questions where the answers would be based entirely on personal opinions, or questions soliciting recommendations for an off-site resource (such as a book, tool, or software library).
   >
   > Consider rephrasing this question to allow it to be answered with facts and citations. [Instead of asking for open-ended recommendations, you should ask how to accomplish a specific task/goal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605).
3. **Unclear**

   > This question cannot be answered in its current form because it lacks a clear problem statement and/or is missing key details.
   >
   > Please edit the question to clarify your specific programming problem and include more details. Make sure to check the comments to see if anyone has requested the inclusion of specific details.
4. **Needs debugging details**

   > This question is asking for help with debugging some code ("why isn't this code working?"), but it is missing the minimum information needed to make it answerable. Debugging questions must include:
   >
   > - the desired behavior (*i.e.*, a clear problem statement),
   > - [a specific problem or error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146) (*e.g.*, an error message or stack trace),
   > - representative input(s) and the expected output(s) [if appropriate], and
   > - the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem (*i.e.*, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).
   >
   > All code and error messages must be included [in the body of the question itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428), and they must be [in text form, not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).
5. **Not reproducible or caused by a typo**

   > The problem(s) described in this question arose due to a typo and/or can no longer be reproduced (*e.g.*, because of a transient failure in a third-party service). While similar questions may be on-topic, the root cause here was a mistake that cannot be identified or reproduced, thus making the solutions unusable for future readers.
   >
   > If you are experiencing a similar problem or have found a way to reliably reproduce this one, then please ask a new question. Make sure to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
6. **Blatantly off-topic**

   > This question is not about programming or software development within the scope defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It does not relate to either a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or a software tool commonly used programmers.
   >
   > Although your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, you may be able to get help elsewhere:
   > <sup><sub>(click to expand)</sub></sup>
   >
   > - Questions about general computing hardware and software can be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).
   > - Questions about Linux, BSD, and other Un*x-like operating systems can be asked on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
   > - Questions about usage of Apple hardware, software, services, and associated products can be asked on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
   > - Questions about general usage of Android devices and applications can be asked on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
   > - Questions about professional system and network administration can be asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).
   > - Questions about database administration and/or design can be asked on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
   > - Questions about operating and managing your own website, including questions about SEO, domain names, and web/email hosting can be asked on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
   > - Questions about statistics, data analysis, and machine learning can be asked on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
   > - Questions about TeX, LaTeX, and related typesetting systems can be asked on [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
   > - Questions about copyright and/or licensing issues can be asked on [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

---

All of the close reasons would be generically described as "unsuitable", such that the "recommend closure" flag would be raised by attempting to flag a question as "unsuitable for this site", and then selecting the specific reason why the question is unsuitable. (The banner presented to the asker of the question could still emphasize "needs improvement", because that's an actionable goal for them. Also, it's apparently friendlier. But the person voting/flagging to close doesn't need to see this. To them, "needs improvement" means "edit". If they can't improve it, then the question is "unsuitable" for the site as posed, and that's the flag/vote they should be raising/casting.)

Most of these reasons are self-explanatory. Although the wording of the explanations is only a first draft, each is carefully crafted to reduce the chances of misunderstanding and misapplication. Notes about each of the reasons and why they were chosen are as follows:

1. The wording "too broad" is brought back to replace the current confusing duality of "needs more focus" and "needs more details". The description of "too broad" also now includes both of the two things that this reason was meant to capture: questions that include a numbered list of multiple questions all-in-one, *and* questions that are inherently too broad to be answered in a Q&A format.
2. The "seeking recommendations" and "opinion-based" reasons are collapsed into one. This is done primarily to reduce the number of different close reasons, which reduces the cognitive burden placed on each close voter. I believe it is manageable to collapse these, considering that both the motivations and the corrective actions for these two close reasons are essentially the same.
3. The wording "unclear" is brought back because it is simply more clear than the current "needs details or clarity".

   As a bonus, I'd love to have a similar feature here to what we already have now for "off-topic", allowing close-voters to type in a specific, detailed explanation of what/why the question is unclear. But this would require more significant changes in the software than just rearranging the reasons, so I would completely understand if this was deferred.
4. The "needs debugging details" reason is kept essentially in its current form, but the explanation is tightened up in hopes of restricting its usage to questions that are actually asking for debugging help (which are the only questions to which it is meant to apply).
5. The "not reproducible or caused by a typo" is also maintained in essentially its current form, with the wording tweaked (and largely borrowed) from [Shog9's answer explaining the intent behind this reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348033).
6. "Blatantly off-topic" is included because duh. Except that this is now the *only* off-topic reason: the current "Super User" and "Server Fault" reasons are removed, because:

   - Fewer reasons are better than more reasons: this is the general theme.
   - Besides, 90% of the time, users on Stack Overflow don't know how to choose correctly between these two reasons anyway.
   - And that shouldn't even be our job. We don't want to have close reasons recommending *specific* places for askers to go. (Askers are on their own to do their research, read the Help Center, and decide which other site, if any, would accept their question—it is not our job to do this work for them, and we don't want to accept the blame for an invalid recommendation. Stack Overflow's user-base can only be expected to be knowledgeable about their *own* site's scope.)

   Out of the kindness of our heart, a general list of *related* Q&A sites, maintained by moderators or staff, can be presented on demand to anyone reading the explanation for a question's closure. Or, maybe, instead of this curated list, we just provide a link to the ["all sites" list on Stack Exchange's homepage](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic).

   When choosing the "blatantly off-topic" reason, users with the requisite privileges would also get an optional textbox, just as they do now, into which they could type a more detailed explanation for why they think the question is off-topic. This explanation would be posted on their behalf as a comment—again, just as happens now.

What's missing? Well, nothing! This covers everything we have now, scattered out as it is over some 9 or 10 different close reasons, depending on how you count, which are themselves divided into confusing hierarchies. Programmers love their hierarchies, but it doesn't make for a good user experience. Besides, the more reasons you have to choose from, the more mentally taxing each closure becomes, and the more frustrated and bitter the curators get.

Oh—one thing is missing: the option for users to migrate a question to another site. That's by design. Moderators would still have the ability to migrate a question elsewhere, but regular users would not have that ability because the large majority of the time, it is misused. As noted above, Stack Overflow users cannot reasonably be expected to be knowledgeable about the scope of any other sites except their own. Thus, they should not be responsible for migrating their unwanted questions to other sites. Besides, migration *in general* results in a relatively poor experience for the asker, doubly so if the recommendation was not quite apt. We just don't need migration. There's no benefit in that over having the asker delete and repost the question on another site. The only benefit to migration is preserving the answers, but considering questions more than 60 days old cannot be migrated anyway, even by moderators, there isn't much concern about the preservation of answers. If an exceptional situation arises, a moderator flag can be raised, as always.

Comment: I really like the idea of getting rid of migration entirely and just putting suggestions under "Blatantly Off Topic". I also agree with restoring the "an answer would be too long" to the Too Broad reason.

Answer (score 6):

I'll share my experience, as someone who recently (after 900 rep and 80 flags) discovered that "A community-specific reason" was actually a menu. Prior to this "discovery", for example, I had always flagged questions needing an mcve as "Needs details or clarity".

I saw posts being closed as "Needs debugging details" or "Not reproducible", but I assumed that those were simply more specific close reasons that only the reviewers had.

Whenever I saw a question with a typo, I flagged as needing moderator intervention and described the problem. To compound the issue, I even got some of the mod flags accepted! It was not until I finally got one declined with the statement:

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

So, I went to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) and saw **absolutely nothing** about typos or reproducibility. For some reason, in the *community-specific wiki about flags* (correction: the privileges wikis are not community-specific, but maybe they should be), the *community-specific flags* **are not listed**! This would be a first thing to change, in my opinion:

- Change the wiki to list the community specific reasons

Continuing my hunt for this mysterious flag, I came across [this MSE post linked on the flag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op/169824#169824), which talks about "Off-topic" flags (which, in my mind, meant nothing as I had never seen such a flag) and contains answers with an outdated UI and "Close votes" ("I can't vote to close, I can only flag!" is what I thought).

It is not (clearly) mentioned in this highly-upvoted post that these reasons would even be behind another menu. This is the second issue I had, which:

- Could be resolved by updating the UI in the answers and changing "Off-topic" to "A community-specific reason". Also, a mention of how to get to these flags would be useful in a post linked as "[Guide to off-topic flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op/169824#169824)"

Lastly, I agree with Cody in his answer: the community-specific flags are too deeply nested. Adding to this, the button to get to these flags looks just like the other reasons, and makes it very **unattractive to click**. *Why would I pick such a broad reason as my flag?*

*P.S. Why is duplicate in "needs improvement"?*