# What "more details" can I provide?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I need help understanding what "more details" I can provide in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76880695/mysql-using-is-not-valid-at-this-position-expecting-an-identifier) to have it reopened, other than posting the stored procedure, which I cannot do.

Comment: It seems people have tried and failed to recreate the issue based on what you've posted. So the additional detail you can provide is: an example that _does_ recreate the issue. _"Did the syntax change with MySQL versions?"_ - which version are you using?

Comment: From the comments, it appears that it's implied that the problem is coming from your IDE, *not* the data engine, however, there's no details of what IDE you're using. The problem is likely stemmed from the fact that it lacks details as it can't be reproduced. Though we can't see, I suspect that some of close votes occured *before* your latest edit, which means they were based on the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76880695/1), which lacked some of the details. Improving your question doesn't invalidate prior (close) votes.

Comment: You must certainly could provide a stored procedure that also exhibited the issue you describe. If you can’t provide an adequate MRE then you likely will have to either recreate the problem to a point where a MRE can be provided or hire an expert to help you figure it out.

Comment: "This used to work fine, but now I get a" - is this a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message? Do you know *where* it is coming from? Do you know *that it is an error* rather than a warning? (i.e., is it *actually preventing you* from executing the code and seeing a result?)

Comment: You don't have to post *the* stored procedure, just one which produces the same error.

Answer (score 19):

The goal when it is a debugging help problem is that someone can reproduce the problem somehow. You can't solve what you cannot reproduce to be able to figure out what the cause is - especially if you don't have access to the machine where it is happening. Full code (altered to not be corporate property if necessary) is really the money maker but besides that you just say *"When I try to run it"* - you fail to mention HOW you are running it. Without knowing HOW you run it, how can anyone faithfully reproduce?

And if you don't mention database versions, how can anyone know if it might be related to a syntax change or maybe a driver version mismatch?

Those are the type of questions you need to ask yourself before you post questions. Re-read what you are about to post and put yourself in the mind of your target audience - will they be able to know what is right in front of you with what you provide? If the answer is not a definitive "yes", you still have work to do.
Stack Overflow is not a helpdesk and debugging requests need to follow the same quality standard rules as any other question - they need to be complete right from the get-go which will require a lot of effort from you to paint a complete picture. Only then will it be useful to other people as well. "I can't" is not an argument to post an incomplete debugging request, if you can't provide then you simply should not post the question *on Stack Overflow*. It's a privilege, not a right.

Answer (score 15):

> This used to work fine...

In what version of MySQL was that true? And since it doesn't work fine now, what version of MySQL are you currently using?

Have you tried any intermediate versions to narrow the range where there's a problem?

> I do get an error when I try to edit the stored procedure...

What error? Is this editing problem the one you want solved, or is it the Stored Procedure hanging problem?

Have you tried using [MySQL's tools](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze/) to examine what's going on? What did they tell you?

These are all details you could add to the question.

Consider how easy or hard it would be for someone else to replicate the problem you have in order for them to help you further, that's what providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is all about.

Comment: The real beauty of the Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE) is not in how it helps us help you, but in how it helps you help yourself. If you use MRE to isolate the problem in the smallest possible code, often you'll find a few divide-and-conquer passes into making the MRE you've reduced the noise around the mistake to be able to spot, understand, and eliminate the mistake without any outside help. And the need to ask the question goes away. Even getting only as far as spotting and understanding the mistake are invaluable to comprehending the solutions you receive when you ask the question.