# Making general advice to author of a question with suggested question

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I am trying to become a more active moderator on SO.  How should I address the following situation.

OP asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35199847), which subsequently had a suggested edit and then closed by another individual as

Is there an appropriate way for me to suggest some more specific content edits to the OP without editing the question myself?  E.g. I would like to suggest specifically that they post their .viminspector.json configuration along with what error condition they are encountering.   Maybe suggest the "template" for a better question, like:

> I am having a problem using viminspector.  I installed it by doing
> XYZ.  But when I tried to do XYZ I got error "XXX" (or X didn't happen
> that I expected to happen).

Is this too much handholding?  Is the link to the "more focus" close reason expected to be sufficient?

IMHO I think giving the user this kind of template will be much more helpful (and lead to more productive questions in general)...

Comment: "*Is there an appropriate way for me to suggest some more specific content edits to the OP without editing the question myself?*" why not leave a comment with questions or suggestions?

Comment: Something seems to be missing near *"by another individual as"*.

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe suggest the "template" for a better question, like:

Based on my experience, this is very unlikely to be productive (despite how tempting it is sometimes) and likely to lead to an argument that risks Code of Conduct violations in the heat of the moment.

> E.g. I would like to suggest specifically that they post their .viminspector.json configuration along with what error condition they are encountering.

The simplest way to do that is to... just do that, directly. Post a comment that asks OP to post the configuration and a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message. Feel free to link that meta question, as well as relevant help center articles such as https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, as appropriate.

Another feasible approach is the Socratic method. For questions that seem to need more focus because solving the problem is a matter of following some logical steps, try to figure out which step OP needs help with by asking about each part and seeing what OP can and can't answer independently. For questions that seem likely to be caused by some trivial typo or logical error, talk the OP through the top-level steps of a debugging process, and make sure that OP has a clear expectation of *what should happen* at each step in the code. For questions where debugging details are missing, ask what details OP has, and what happens as a result of trying certain specific debugging actions (e.g. "does it work with XYZ input / if you rename the file" etc.).

Comment: I always like to remind folks that they don't have to memorize URLs like that: they can just use `[mre]` and it will substitute [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (except on Meta sites). The exhaustive list being on [the SE meta here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/194720).

Comment: Yea but then we have to memorize what is and isn't a short link, when often they use non-sensical abbreviations, such as "mre"

Comment: Having confused a few people like that, my work-around is `[mre] (MRE)`.

Comment: @KevinB "mre" is a nonsensical abbreviation for minimal reproducible example? Of course, from the link provided with my comment, `[mcve]`, `[reprex]`, `[repro]`, and `[example]` all link to the same page...

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, but I recall it not working on Meta. Not in answers, anyway.

Comment: Related: *[Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/)*. [An answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000) covers magic links in comments, questions/answers, and chat. (Related to that, *[Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332237/documentation-for-stack-exchange-engine-urls)* and *[List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566)* (that is, for the latter, hidden (sort of magic) URLs))